# Hibernate many-to-many relationship query the Entity without its collection elements

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jax-rs

Description: I have a many to many relationship between User and Shoplist entity. I am making a rest api and I want to query only the User when someone makes a GET to /users/{id}. If I try to get the user from DB it says that the collection of shoplist is not inizialized but that's exactly what I want, only the user without his shoplists. If I get User's shoplists it works fine but that's not what I want.

My entities:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

private String lastname;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String email;

private String password;

@Column(nullable = true) //maybe set @ColumnDefault()
private URL avatar;


@JsonIgnoreProperties("users")
@JoinTable(
        name = "User_Shoplist",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "shoplist_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
@ManyToMany
private Set<Shoplist> shoplists = new HashSet<>();

// getters and setter
```

**Shoplist.java**

```
@Entity
public class Shoplist implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String name;


@JsonIgnoreProperties("shoplists")
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shoplists")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

// getters and setter
```

**Controller.java**

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response index() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        User u1 = session.get(User.class, 1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        return Response.status(200).entity(u1).build();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

}
```

**Goal** : As I previously said, I want to return information about the User without all his shoplists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your entity is serialized to JSON, all getters are called (including `getShoplists`), and because this is happenning outside of the transaction you get LazyInitializationException. This is one of the reasons why entity objects should never leave the service.

You need to create DTO (data transfer object), assign only those values that you need to send (all that still in the transaction), and send the dto instead of an entity.

For example

```java
public class UserDto {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String lastname;
  private String email;
  // btw, this is probably not a good idea to send user password to the client
  // ...
  // getters and setters
}
```

```java
  session.beginTransaction();
  User u1 = session.get(User.class, 1);

  UserDto dto = new UserDto();
  dto.setName(u1.getName());
  // map other values

  session.getTransaction().commit();
  session.close();

  return Response.status(200).body(dto).build();
```

[Baeldung's tutorial on this using ModelMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application)

[A good alternative (Mapstruct)](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct)